# 4th order statistics of Circularly Symmetric Complex Normal random vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume that ${\bf z} \in C^{n×1}$ is a CSCG random vector denoted with $C (μ,Σ)$ where $μ$ and $Σ$ are mean and contrivance matrix, respectively, and defined as

$μ=E({\bf z})$, $Σ=E({\bf z}{\bf z}^H)$.

How can I obtain the following expectations versus $μ$ and $Σ$.?

$E({\bf z}{\bf z}^H⊗{\bf z}^*{\bf z}^T)$